# Indexed element access in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, eclipselink, jpql

Is it possible to do indexed element access in JPQL like in [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) :

```
select o from Order o where o.items[0].id = 1234
```

I couldn't find something related in the JPA 2 specs,

I am targeting [EclipseLink JPA](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php) here, so if you come up with an EclipseLink solution, that's ok as well, although a JPQL standard solution is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The INDEX function should do the trick (actually I tested it and it does):

```
SELECT o
FROM Order o JOIN o.items i
WHERE i.id = 1234
AND INDEX(i) = 0
```

From the JPA 2.0 specification (**4.6.17.2.2 Arithmetic Functions**):

> The INDEX function returns an integer
>   value corresponding to the position of
>   its argument in an ordered list. The
>   INDEX function can only be applied to
>   identification variables denoting
>   types for which an order column has
>   been specified.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Pascal Thivent is correct. In order to make `INDEX()` work you also need to add a `@OrderedColumn` on the entity's collection field.

Be careful, there is a bug in Hibernate, which makes `INDEX()` not work as expect,
it doesn't support `@OrderedColumn` and `mappedBy` together:
[JPA 2.0 @OrderColumn annotation in Hibernate 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5)