# @OrderColumn annotation in Hibernate 3.5

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

I'm trying to use the `@OrderColumn` annotation with Hibernate 3.5

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderColumn(name = "pos")
private List<Children> childrenCollection;
```

When retrieving data, everything works fine. But I can't make it reorder elements in the List and save the new order to the database.

Comment: Can you show how do you re-order your list and save back to database ???

Comment: I've tried creating new ArrayList and 

    parent.setChildrenCollection(newList)

I've tried Collections.sort on retrieved list. I've also tried removing null items from collection. Nothing happened. Other channges in parent were saved to database, but nothing happened with the list.

Comment: isn't Hibernate 3.5 for JPA 1.0, and @OrderColumn is JPA 2.0?!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The combination of @OneToMany(mappedBy="...") and @OrderColumn is not supported by Hibernate.  This JIRA issue tracks a request to throw a more obvious error message when this invalid combination is used: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5390

I think that this isn't supported mainly because it is an odd relational pattern.  The annotations above indicate that the "one" side of the relationship determines how the relationship will be flushed to the database, but the order/position is only available on the "many" side by examining the List.  It makes more sense for the "many" side to own the relationship, since that side knows about both the membership and the ordering of the elements.

The Hibernate Annotations docs describe this situation in some detail:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir

The workaround is to remove the "mappedBy" attribute, which will cause the association to use the default join table strategy instead of a column on the target table.  You can specify the name of the join table using the @JoinTable annotation.

The net effect of this change is that the "many" side of the relationship now determines how the relationship is persisted.  Your java code needs to ensure that the List is updated properly, because Hibernate will now disregard the "one" side when flushing the entities.

If you still want to have the "one" side accessible in Java, map it with

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="...", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
```

Comment: It's funny, that the "official" example for explicit index columns uses exactly the combination `@OneToMany(mappedBy="...")` + `@OrderColumn` (see example 7.8 in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-indexed)

Comment: After this answer it was agreed that the situation has to be supported anyway. Gail Badner: "I agree that that @OneToMany (mappedBy="...") should be supported."

Comment: Is there another JPA provider (like Eclipselink) that supports `@OneToMany (mappedBy="...")`?

Comment: My naive guess is that every provider supports this, as it's a pretty standard mapping. As usual, Hibernate is the odd one out. It's basically the IE6 under the JPA providers :(

Comment: As usual, Hibernate gets in the way: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5732

Comment: I have no idea why this is an "odd relational pattern". It isn't. Just ask the JPA people.

Comment: Bad hibernate bug link, should be https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5390. I cannot edit post "Suggested edit queue is full".

Answer (score 10):

Do something like this:

```
@Entity
class Parent {

    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn(name = "pos")
    List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
class Child {

    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent;
    @Column(name = "pos")
    Integer index;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void prepareIndex() {
        if (parent != null) {
            index = parent.children.indexOf(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in prepareIndex() it should be changed to
index = parent.children.indexOf(this);
if (index == -1) index = parent.children.size();

Answer (score 4):

You should try to specify OrderColumn on the owner of the association.
Or in your mapping you put the owner on the child, the owner should be the parent (on a bidirectionnal association, the owner is the one which doesn't have the keyword mappedBy, here you put this keyword on the parent's class, then you mean the parent's class is not the owner)

In your children class you should have the keyword mappedBy on the parentCollection. But not on the childrenCollection.
And in your parent class you should have the annotation @JoinTable, something like this :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderColumn(name = "pos")
@JoinTable( name = "<NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE>", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( <JOIN_COLUMNS_...> )
private List<Children> childrenCollection;
```