# Distinguish owning and inverse side of a JPA relationship without "mappedBy"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a problem with JPA/Hibernate and the mapping of `@OneToMany` together with `@OrderColumn`. And I found out that this is probably a problem of a [missing distinction between the "owning" and the "inverse" side](http://www.coderanch.com/t/217090/ORM/java/Hibernate-Primary-Key-Violation) of the relationship.

But [Hibernate does not support the following combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="...")
@OrderColumn(...)
```

**How can I tell JPA/Hibernate which side the owning side is?**

I tried it with

```
@OneToMany
@OrderColumn(...)
@JoinTable(name="...")
```

but it didn't help.

It seems to be a [Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5390) (tried Hibernate 3.6.1 and 3.6.9). Is the combination of `mappedBy` and `@OrderColumn` supported by another JPA provider like EclipseLink?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA 2.0 @OrderColumn annotation in Hibernate 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5)

Comment: I linked that question already my question. My question is not a duplicate but an addition.

Comment: "mappedBy" in JPA is to make the relation bidirectional. Omitting it means it is unidirectional, hence "owning" is self-evident.

Comment: @DataNucleus `mappedBy` doesn't work with `@OrderColumn`, but I need to mark one side of the bidirectional relationship as the owning side.

Comment: @deamon The JPA spec mandates "mappedBy" to mark the relation as bidirectional. Fact. What "works" or otherwise (in Hibernate) is a different issue. OrderColumn is to make a List as "indexed" rather than using some "order by" clause, i.e a separate concept. DataNucleus JPA certainly allows bidirectional indexed lists

Comment: What version of Hibernate did you try? It seems they originally interpreted the spec wrongly, but later admitted to their mistake. This was a long time ago, so you'd think it is implemented by now. @DataNucleus do you know if this is covered by the TCK?

Comment: @Mike sorry I don't know if its in the JPA2 TCK; the TCK is of course secret, and Oracle prevented the DataNucleus project from access despite fulfilling all of their requirements and administration. We can only hope they improve on this with JPA2.1 and provide an open source TCK so everyone can check compliance, then people are in a better position to decide what to use for their project

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 3.6.1 (delivered with Play framework).

Comment: It's a bit offtopic, but a TCK doesn't have to be secret. The CDI one is opensource. Hope that this will improve indeed for JPA.

Comment: Also see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the change of question, such a combination is supported by DataNucleus JPA, as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_list.html#join_bi
just replace the @OrderId in that example by @OrderColumn

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've found the workaround to put a `position` into the class (`Task`) whose objects should be ordered.

```
@Entity
public class TaskList extends GenericModel {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="taskList", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  @OrderBy("position")
  public List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addTask(int position, task) {
    task.taskList = this;
    tasks.add(position, task);
    updatePositions();
  }

  private void updatePositions() {
    int position = 0;
    for(Whish whish : whishes)
      whish.setPosition(position++);
  }
}
```

Maybe other JPA providers do a better job in this case, but I have to stick with Hibernate for now.