# Adding index on a existing table in hibernate

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, indexing, jpa-2.0

I have OneToMany relationship between Job and Detail entities and both have common parent(BaseEntity)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Version
@Column(name = "version")
private Integer version;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "create_time")
private Date createTime;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "last_update_time")
private Date lastUpdateTime;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    createTime = new Date();
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    lastUpdateTime = new Date();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public Date getCreateTime() {
    return createTime;
}

public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
    this.createTime = createTime;
}

public Date getLastUpdateTime() {
    return lastUpdateTime;
}

public void setLastUpdateTime(Date lastUpdateTime) {
    this.lastUpdateTime = lastUpdateTime;
}
}
```

Job

```
public class Job extends BaseEntity {

    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Detail> detailList;
    ...
}
```

Detail

```
@Entity
public class Detail extends BaseEntity {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Job job;
    ...
}
```

The job table has about 200K rows, and the detail table has 3M rows. If I get the details of a specific job, it takes 2sec with a native query. I created index for job_id column by running sql statement. And the query response is about 20 msec now. However, the app is in production now and it has data therefore I want to create the index by adding annotation not running sql statement. I added @OrderColumn annotation in order to create index, and while fetching it gives the following exception. By the way, the job_id column on Detail table was named by hibernate. I did not explicitly give a name for the column.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection: tr.com.ttnet.beyazfatura.model.Job.detailList
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readIndex(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:770)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.readFrom(PersistentList.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:1156)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:622)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2166)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:627)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at tr.com.ttnet.beyazfatura.ejb.ModelOperations.getJobs(ModelOperations.java:488)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:37)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:50)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy250.getJobs(Unknown Source)
    at tr.com.ttnet.beyazfatura.ejb.ModelOperations_vrg1wg_ModelOperationsLocalImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:39)
    at tr.com.ttnet.beyazfatura.ejb.ModelOperations_vrg1wg_ModelOperationsLocalImpl.getJobs(Unknown Source)
    at tr.com.ttnet.datamodel.JobLazyDataModel.load(JobLazyDataModel.java:86)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:644)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:178)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:103)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:61)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:185)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:108)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1651)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1651)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1651)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.ttnet.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
2012-02-13 14:08:41,462 WARN  (LoadContexts.java:132) - fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext@d39617<rs=weblogic.jdbc.
wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl@a67>
2012-02-13 14:08:41,463 WARN  (CollectionLoadContext.java:370) - On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " However, the app is in production now and it has data therefore I
>   want to create the index by adding annotation not running sql
>   statement"

Wrong.  It is more important to use a script when creating indexes in production than in other environments.  There needs to be a proper round of impact analysis and configuration management.

Anyway, I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the annotation.  `@OrderColumn` provides an *array index* for controlling the order of the records in the result set, and appears to have no significance for improving performance of the underlying database query.   (However I am a database person rather a Hibernate person, so my interpretation may be wrong.)

As for why you get that specific excpetion, try reading [this response to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480336/146325).

Comment: I took this statement as a solution "It is more important to use a script when creating indexes in production than in other environments." Thank you.