# HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I got a strange exception. My mappings :

```
public class ConcreteProduct {

...

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "concreteProduct")
    public Set<ExternalClient> getExternalClients() {
        return externalClients;
    }
....

}

public class ExternalClient {
 ...
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_concrete_product")
    public ConcreteProduct getConcreteProduct() {
        return concreteProduct;
    }
..
}
```

And I Want to make a simple operations on ConcreteProduct using Hibernate operations. I use crudDAO:

```
 ConcreteProduct concreteProduct = (ConcreteProduct) crudDAO.getById( ConcreteProduct.class, list.get( 0 )
                .getId() );
            if ( concreteProduct != null ) {
                finishCalculation( concreteProduct );
                crudDAO.save( concreteProduct );
            }
```

and there is an exception :

> Exception in thread "Thread-33" org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.eo.apps.mops.product.bo.ConcreteProduct.externalClients; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.eo.apps.mops.product.bo.ConcreteProduct.externalClients
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.eo.apps.mops.product.bo.ConcreteProduct.externalClients

Maybe important thing is that whole operation is processed within a Thread. What is causing the problem here?

Comment: the finishCalculation() method is not important, if I delete this line of my code the exception also occurs

Comment: Could this be a problem you are facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5/3480336#3480336 ?

Comment: unfortunately no, there is not a single place in my application with OrderColumn annotation

Comment: I'm gonna try to remove the "mapped by" element and see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: @Dawid I know this is an old post, but have you found any solution?  I may be facing the same problem.

Comment: @bphilipnyc to be honest I don't remember. It was a long time ago and soon after that I switched to Rails