# Hibernate : EAGER fetch on grandchildren while LAZY fetch children

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6.Final

I have 3 classes :

- Parent
- Child
- Grandchild

As you can imagine, a Parent has many Children, and a Child has many Grandchildren.

```
class Parent {

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderColumn(name = "list_order")
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
@Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Child {

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false, 
foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_child_parent_id"))
private Parent parent;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderColumn(name = "list_order")
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
@Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Grandchild> grandchildren = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Grandchild {
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false,
foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_grandchild_child_id"))
private Child child;
}
```

I want to LAZY load Children but EAGER load Grandchildren when loading Children.

Which means that :

- When I access Parent, I want Hibernate to fetch only Parent
- But if I call parent.getChildren(), I want Hibernate to fetch all children AND grandchildren

I've set EAGER on Child<->Granchild association, but it has no effect : when I call parent.getChildren(), only the children are fetched, not the grandchildren.

Thanks for your help !

UPDATE @Zeus, in my database :

- Table Parent has "id"
- Table Child has "id", "parent_id" (foreign key of parent) and "list_order" (used by Hibernate to order the list of children)
- Table Grandchild has "id", "child_id" (foreign key of child) and "list_order"

Comment: Which version of the hibernate you have? Also put some code, your associations definition.

Comment: Can you also give your table structure. i'm concerned about the foreignKey attribute in the grandchild. I believe it is not required. You may be mapping one-one with child and grndchild

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5 issue with orderColumn

Comment: This is not the same issue... The one you're pointing at is about orderColumn with mappedBy issue, which is not how I mapped my elements. The issue I face is about EAGER fetching...