# JPA @OrderBy doesn't sort relationships

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having following Entities:

```
public class QuestionnaireTemplateEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="questionnaireTemplate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("subQuestionnaireOrder ASC")
    private Set<SubQuestionnaireTemplateEntity> subQuestionnaires = new HashSet<>();
}


public class SubQuestionnaireTemplateEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="subQuestionnaireTemplate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("questionOrder ASC")
    private Set<QuestionEntity> questions = new HashSet<>();
    private Integer subQuestionnaireOrder;
}

public class QuestionEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sub_questionnaire_template_id")
    private SubQuestionnaireTemplateEntity subQuestionnaireTemplate;
    private Integer questionOrder;
}
```

Now when I retrieve all the QuestionnaireTemplate I would expect every relationship is sorted but this isn't. Nothing is sorted it's always random.

```
questionnaireTemplateRepository.findAll()
```

Comment: Does it work when you use `List` instead of `Set`?

Comment: You can also try to use `SortedSet`

Comment: My own stupid fault. It's indeed because of the Set. Both SortedSet and List works. If you answer the question I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the '@OrderBy' annotation, I always use the annotation '@OrderColumn'. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12484332/10902231) provides a simple example how to implement this annotation to achieve ordering in Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But when I look up the difference between those two annotations this OrderColumn adds a new column that tracks the position when an element changes then the position is also updated. I don't know if that's what I want. When using OrderBy with a List or SortedSet it works.

Comment: You already have an integer attribute which you want to use to order. You just have to say that this should be your order column.