# Spring Data JPA sort by join table @OrderColumn?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data JPA to query a `User` entity that has a collection of `UserGroup`s. The ordering of these groups is significant, so I've declared an `@OrderColumn` on the relationship:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    @OrderColumn
    private List<UserGroup> groups;
}
```

I need to query the groups for a particular user, and I want them to come back in the order specified by the `@OrderColumn` in the join table. I have this query method in my `UserGroupRepository`.

```java
public Page<UserGroup> findByUsersIdContains(String userId, Pageable pageable);
```

That query does not honor the ordering I want. Is there something I can add to the method name, or specifying in the `Sort` definition within the `Pageable`, to order by the order column in the join table?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a column name which should be used for ordering the relationship. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12484332/10902231) shows how the annotation `@OrderColumn` could be used. Even though the example is for a `@OneToMany` relationship, this ordering should also work for `@ManyToMany`.