# JPQL single collection element in WHERE

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join, jpql

I'm creating a small forum. The entities and their relations are like this:

Entity `Topic` has a `OneToMany` relation to `Post`, `Post` has a `ManyToOne` relation to `User`

I want to get all topics for one specific user by checking the author of the first post in each topic. Here is my JPQL:

```
SELECT t FROM Topic t JOIN t.posts p WHERE p.user=:user
```

But this WHERE will check all posts in topic, I only want to check the first post (This user will be considered as the author of the topic).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better solution here: [Indexed element access in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924847/indexed-element-access-in-jpql)

Basically I can use `INDEX()` in JPQL to describe the index of collection:

```
SELECT t FROM Topic t JOIN t.posts p WHERE p.user = :user AND INDEX(p) = 0
```

In order to make `INDEX()` work, I need to add a `@OrderedColumn` on `Topic` entity's `posts` field:

```
@OrderColumn(name = "order_column")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "topic")
private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

The problem is, there is a bug in Hibernate, it doesn't support `@OrderedColumn` and `mappedBy` together:
[JPA 2.0 @OrderColumn annotation in Hibernate 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5)

As a solution I update the order column manually in entity `Post`:

```
@Column(name = "order_column")
private Integer orderColumn;

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void updateOrderColumn() {
    // for changing order
    orderColumn = topic.getPosts().indexOf(this);
    // for persist
    if (orderColumn == -1)
        orderColumn = topic.getPosts().size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use native query, with sub select on join, so that

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM topics t JOIN posts p ON p.topic_id = (SELECT topic_id FROM posts p1 WHERE p1.topic_id = t.id ORDER BY p1.id ASC LIMIT 1) WHERE p.user_id = :userId", nativeQuery=true)
List<Topic> findTopicsByUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```